# Сборка в alpine linux. Не линкуется

Tags: linux, gcc, alpine-linux

Беру [любой пример](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-example.html) из документации и пытаюсь собрать под AlpineLinux.

```
# gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs  libpq) test.c
```

Вот такие дела получаются.

```
/tmp/ccbcedGJ.o: In function `exit_nicely':
test.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
/tmp/ccbcedGJ.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
test.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
test.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
test.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `PQexec'
test.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
test.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
test.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `PQexec'
test.c:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
test.c:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
test.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `PQexec'
test.c:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
test.c:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
test.c:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `PQnfields'
test.c:(.text+0x221): undefined reference to `PQfname'
test.c:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `PQgetvalue'
test.c:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `PQntuples'
test.c:(.text+0x2be): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x2d1): undefined reference to `PQexec'
test.c:(.text+0x2e1): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x2f4): undefined reference to `PQexec'
test.c:(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `PQclear'
test.c:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Сборка в объектный файл проходит удачно. `libpq libpq-dev musl-dev` стоят. `pkg-config` показывает правильно `-lpq`. Линковку библиотек через ldd проверял.

Дело не только в `libpq`. `libuv` тоже не линкуется.

```
# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-alpine-linux-musl
Configured with: /home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --host=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --target=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --with-pkgversion='Alpine 6.3.0' --enable-checking=release --disable-fixed-point --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-default-pie --enable-cloog-backend --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,java,fortran,ada --disable-libssp --disable-libmpx --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 (Alpine 6.3.0)
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот так: *gcc  test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs  libpq)*

Comment: а разница? от перемены мест ничего нового не получится

Comment: вот черт! получилось

Comment: @Sergey, запостите ответом?

Comment: Потому что это про линковщик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда запускается линкер, в командной строке ему передаётся список объектных модулей, подлежащих линковке. Он просматривает этот список **последовательно**, переходя от первого к последнему.

На протяжении процесса сборки программы, линкер ведёт таблицу всё ещё НЕ разрешённых внешних ссылок. Таким образом, если в командной строке сначала идёт библиотека, а потом ОМ, который эту библиотеку использует, то происходит следующее:

1. Линкер просматривает файл библиотеки и видит, что ей ничего не нужно.
2. Линкер переходит к ОМ и видит, сто у него есть неразрешённые ссылки. он запоминает их.
3. Далее он пытается обработать очередной ОМ/библиотеку, но в командной строке уже ничего нет. Ему не остаётся ничего другог, как напечатаь сообщение об ошибке и завершить работу.

Поэтому, команда

```
gcc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libpq)
```

работает, а команда

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs  libpq) test.c
```

нет.

Comment: отличный ответ, я думал вяжется всё, а потом стрипом вычистят кому что не нужно